# How to reword properly "Stick to the plan at any circumstances"?

Tags: phrase-request

I changed  "at" --> "under" and "stick" --> "adhere". Doesn't work. Google finds no results *at all.*

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+the+plan%2Cstick+to+the+plan%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollow%20the%20plan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstick%20to%20the%20plan%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+any+case%2C+no+matter+what+happens%2C+under+any+circumstances%2C+at+any+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20any%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20matter%20what%20happens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20any%20circumstances%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20any%20cost%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your sentence:

> Stick to the plan at any circumstances.

This sounds strange.  Let's break it down:

- *Stick to the plan* is fine.  Don't change it to *adhere* – that doesn't sound as good.
- *At any circumstances* sounds strange.  *Under any circumstances* sounds more natural, but it doesn't fit really well with your sentence as a whole.

I would rephrase it like this:

> Stick to the plan **no matter what happens**.

I think this sounds natural enough.

Comment: "At any circumstances" sounds extremely non-fluent to this native US English speaker, so much so that I really can't recommend it at all.  Google Means finds basically no results for it.  I think the best option is probably for the OP to use a different phrase entirely.

Comment: @stangdon I agree.  That's why I said the same thing in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hold to the plan anyhow.

Hold to the plan by any means.

You could use *abide to/by* as well, but *abide to/by the plan* doesn't sound great.

Comment: I think  “Stick to the plan in any circumstances”- is fine.

Comment: Same here. It can be left as is, if rephrasing is not really needed.

Comment: @engfan, unfortunately, Google doesn't think so

Comment: Hold to the plan sounds very strange.

Comment: @Serguei: I searched for 'at any circumstance'- couldn't find it.http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/circumstance

Comment: How about: *Stick to the plan at all costs*

Comment: Too dramatic :(

Comment: @engfan, try  "at any circumstanceS"

Comment: @Serguei : yes I did checked "at any circumstances" . I think we can either say 'in any' or 'under any'  circumstances.

Comment: please refer the link

Comment: ?? _What_ do you want me to do?